# UINavigationController subclass and transitionCoordinator

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

We are using a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` that displays a custom view instead of the `UINavigationBar` only for the first view controller.

For that, we override `pushViewController` and `popViewController` to animate out and in our custom view.

The code for `pushViewController` looks like:

```
override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

    defer { showTopViewIfNeeded(animated: animated) }

    guard let transitionCoordinator = viewController.transitionCoordinator else { return }

    transitionCoordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: self.view, animation: { (context) in

        let fromViewController = context.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)

        if fromViewController == self.viewControllers.first {

            var navigationViewFrame = self.topNavigationView.frame
            navigationViewFrame.origin.x -= navigationViewFrame.size.width
            self.topNavigationView.frame = navigationViewFrame
        }
    }, completion:nil)

}
```

Basically, I call the `super` implementation, so a `transitionCoordinator` gets created (it's `nil` until I call that), and then I animate the view alongside the transition.

The `popViewController` is similar and just reverses the animation (by changing the origin back o zero).

The problem I experience, is that the first time a view controller is pushed, the animation doesn't happen. Instead, the frame of the custom view changes immediately.

Upon popping, and pushing again, the animation works perfectly.

To make it even weirder, this works fine in iOS 9 and iOS 10 simulators, and only fails in iOS 11.

Does my code look ok? Is the way I'm interacting with the `transitioningCoordinator` standard? I'm trying to understand if this is an iOS 11 issue, or my code's.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you do - for me it started to appear when I nested 2 navigation controllers. Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Once the outer navigation controller has pushed a VC, the problem disappears.

Comment: No... we are leaving with the big for now.

Comment: The workaround I'm using at the moment is ugly, but might work for you too: I replaced my root view controller with a placeholder that matches my splashscreen. In its `viewDidAppear`, I dispatch to the main queue and push my actual root view controller using a custom fade animation (which makes it look like the splashscreen fading out). I added a completion block to the `pushViewController` method of my NavController, in which I replace the splashscreen with my usual root VC. Now all animations seem to work just fine! I can make this an answer and add code if you'd like.

Comment: If you're subclassing `UINavigationController`, just go whole hog and do it all custom—no need to override anything.

Comment: We might go the whole way, yes...

Subclassing allowed us for a quicker turnaround on this new design, and we hope we can ditch our custom code somewhere down the road. Subclassing made sense for that.